# Building OR expressions in the WHERE clause with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I need to create a SQL Linq with a `WHERE` clause containing an `OR` expression. Its operands are stored in a `List`.

With this piece of code, I end up getting an AND expression:

```
private sigdaEntities db = new sigdaEntities();

List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("Nom");
list.Add("Representant");


IQueryable<ExplotacionsAgraries> consulta = db.ExplotacionsAgraries;
foreach (string DataColumn in list) {
    if (DataColumn=="Nom") {
        consulta.Where(x => x.nom.Contains(valueSearch));
    }

    if (DataColumn=="Representant") {
    consulta.Where(x => x.representant.Contains(valueSearch));
    }
}
```

What can I do to get an `OR` expression instead?

Comment: You need to assign the result of adding the `where` operator, eg. `consulta = consulta.Where(x => x.nom.Contains(valueSearch))`

Comment: Can you share your desired sql output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the OR manually with multiple [`.Union()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.union?view=netframework-4.7.2) statements.

I also changed to using `list.Contains()` because to me it seems to reflect better what the code is doing.

```
IQueryable<ExplotacionsAgraries> consulta = db.ExplotacionsAgraries;

if (list.Any()) {

    // Start with "nothing":
    var result = consulta.Take(0);

    // Add results from each filter:
    if (list.Contains("Nom"))
        result = result.Union(consulta.Where(x => x.nom.Contains(valueSearch)));

    if (list.Contains("Representant"))
        result = result.Union(consulta.Where(x => x.representant.Contains(valueSearch));

    // And keep the final result
    consulta = result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is what you're looking for, but you can make use of the [`Queryable.Union`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.union?view=netframework-4.7.2) method, which will

> Produces the set union of two sequences.

Your code will look like this:

```
IQueryable<ExplotacionsAgraries> consulta = db.ExplotacionsAgraries;
var result = null;
foreach (string DataColumn in list) 
{
    if (DataColumn=="Nom") 
    {
        if (result == null) 
        {
            result = consulta.Where(x => x.nom.Contains(valueSearch));
        }
        else 
        {
            result = result.Union(consulta.Where(x => x.nom.Contains(valueSearch)));
        }
    }

    if (DataColumn=="Representant") 
    {
        if (result == null) 
        {
            result = consulta.Where(x => x.representant.Contains(valueSearch));
        }
        else 
        {
            result = result.Union(consulta.Where(x => x.representant.Contains(valueSearch)));
        }
    }
}
```

Code is not tested, but it should do the job in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
IQueryable<ExplotacionsAgraries> consulta = db.ExplotacionsAgraries;
consulta.Where(x => (list.Contains("Nom") &&  x.nom.Contains(valueSearch))
                       || (list.Contains("Representant") && x.representant.Contains(valueSearch)));
```

Comment: This produces no results if `list` is empty or if `list` does not contain any of the keywords. The original code does not apply filtering in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do
    `db.ExplotacionsAgraries.Where(x => (list.Any(i => i == "Nom") && 
    x.nom.Contains(valueSearch)) || (list.Any(i => i == "Representant") && 
    x.representant.Contains(valueSearch)))`

Comment: This produces no results if `list` is empty or if `list` does not contain any of the keywords. The original code does not apply filtering in such cases.

Comment: @PeterB if the list does not contain any of the keywords, then there will be no filtering on the result set and it will return all of the records.

Comment: No, it will behave like `db.ExplotacionsAgraries.Where(x => false || false)`